# How to parse a html String on the parse.com Cloude Code platform?

Tags: javascript, html, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I use parse.com for a small and simple backend and I try to scrape a webpage for some image urls.

I was able to load the html from the site into a string with parse.com Cloud Code.

But now I need to convert the html into a document or another searchable structure. 
Is there a way to create a document from the html that I can use to search for specific tags?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by document. But if you want to write the html into a file, you can do something like `var buf = new Buffer(htmlString, 'utf8'); var base64String = buf.toString('base64') var file = new Parse.File('index.html', {base64: base64String});`

Comment: I want to generate a DOM Object or some tree structure that allows me to get specific tags by classes or ids.

Comment: Oh, then you need a package like https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio but since parse is not a node.js environment, you can't have packages using node's internal apis. https://www.parse.com/questions/using-npm-modules-in-cloud-code